# Fetching data from db when the time is stored as 2016-3-7 12:23:01

Tags: php

How do i fetch the data stored in the  db as timestamp from time to time? following is my code

```
require("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//$id=$_POST['indate'];
$start_date=$_POST['indate'];
$end_date=$_POST['outdate'];

$start_time=strtotime("2016-8-5 00:00:00");
$end_time=strtotime("2016-9-5 23:59:59");

$query= "SELECT date_time FROM data2 WHERE date_time BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'  ";
// if(!$query){

//  die("invalid query ".mysqli_error());
// } 



$sql=mysqli_query($dbCon,$query) or die ('error');


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['date_time'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
}
```

when the user enters id and datefrom to dateto it should show me the data. such as
 id 1, indate=2016-06-09  20:16:45  out date =2016-06-09  23:18:07.
it should display me the data between two ranges.

Comment: show some code so we get a clear picture

Comment: Read the manual at http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php you can easily convert your second time to a time interval.

Comment: Your question needs to show the searches you already did. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more informations

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
$datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s','22:31:19');
$datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s','28:44:21');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S'); //06:13:02
```